# Filter product collection to remove products missing an image

Tags: magento2, image, product-collection

I can't find how to do this in Magento 2 (plenty of info on magento 1, but I don't know if it is the same code?).

In the product collection code, when adding addAttributeToFilter() - what code do I need to use to filter out products that are missing an image?

Something like this (from Magento 1 code) maybe?

```
->addAttributeToFilter('image', array("neq"=>'no_selection'))
```

Could someone confirm please?

Comment: This should work don't see why it wouldn't

Comment: I guess I should have just tried it before posting!! Works fine :-)

Answer (score 3):

In Magento 2, yourModule/etc/di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer">

<plugin name="exclude_no_image_product" type="yourCompany\yourModule\Model\Rewrite\LayerPlugin"/>

  </type>
```

Add file yourCompany\yourModule\Model\Rewrite\LayerPlugin.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace yourCompany\yourModule\Model\Rewrite;

/**
 * Catalog view layer model
 *
 * @api
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.LongVariable)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
class LayerPlugin
{ 
    /**
     * Retrieve current layer product collection
     *
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection
     */
    public function aroundgetProductCollection(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer $subject, \Closure $proceed)
    {
        $collection = $proceed();        
        $collection
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('small_image', array('neq' => 'no_selection'))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('small_image', array('neq' => ''))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('small_image', array('neq' => null));
        return $collection;
    }    
}
```

It will work. I have found and i am using in my website. Learn more.. www.webizon.in